# Gem::LoadError: when trying to deploy on Heroku - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku

I am trying to deploy an app (just a simple app from a Rails tutorial) to heroku but it keeps giving me the same error message. I use the command:

```
git push heroku master
```

It starts well, and then suddenly appears this error:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile.
```

I did bundle install already, everything went smooth there.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Maybe something I am missing something on databse.yml file?

```
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

By the way, I don't know if it helps, but I am using Rails 4.0.4, Ruby 2.1.1 and the version of SQLite which comes already installed on Mac, which is 3.7.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQLite** is not intended as a production grade database. Instead Heroku provides production grade **PostgreSQL** databases as a service.

Read the details **[SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)**

Comment: BUT you are deploying that simple app on Heroku and Heroku doesn't support sqlite3. Size of the app doesn't matter here.

Comment: I see, I was just curious because I have been following the tutorial video step by step, and on his' it works. Maybe something changed on heroku from that time to now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer when timeout is over. :)

Comment: I will for sure, thanks! I tried to vote up, but since I'm a newbie it doesn't allow me to do it :(

Comment: Yes, up vote is not allowed BUT you can accept the answer by checking the checkmark next to my answer, under 0.

Answer (score 3):

Kirti is right in saying that Heroku does not support sqlite as adapter,

do the following

**in the Gemfile:**

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

**in database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: name_of_your_db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```