# Heroku deploy from cloud9. sqllite3 needed, but i have it specified for development only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my rails application databse to heroku.

I'm using this command

heroku run rake db:migrate

Ther error im getting is the following

> Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ mighty-lowlands-99868... up, run.8184 (Free)
>   rake aborted!
>   Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

My gem file is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#gem 'ruby', '2.3.4'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
#Authentication Gem -> https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance
gem 'clearance', '~> 1.16.1'
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
#Gem for search
#https://github.com/karmi/retire
gem 'tire'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.4'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem "chartkick"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
end


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Any idea what the solution is

Datebasae.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gem::LoadError: when trying to deply on Heroku - Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941849/gemloaderror-when-trying-to-deply-on-heroku-rails-4)

Comment: What databases are you setting in database.yml?

Comment: @Pablo i've added that in now

Comment: You still have the sqlite database for production, see [Alok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942161/5025116).

Comment: but what do i name the db/how do I find the name

Answer (score 1):

You are using pg in your gemfile for production environment (this is correct). **Edit**: As commented below, you must specify a supported pg gem version. Use 0.21.0 as 1.0.0 is still not supported.

However, you are using sqlite3 on your databse.yml for production environment.

Moreover, Heroku does not support Sqlite.

To use pg on Heroku, just add the Heroku pg add-on. When you push code, Heroku will replace your database.yml to use the correct database. You don't need the name, username or password. They will be set as environment variables. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior

Comment: I get this error now. Even though PG is specified and it's installed. Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Comment: You must specify a supported pg gem version. Use 0.21.0 as 1.0.0 is still not supported.

Comment: Sorted that. This hopefully is my last issue > heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ mighty-lowlands-99868... up, run.4332 (Free)
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336844/error-when-run-migrations-on-heroku-posgresql-with-rails-5

Comment: Great thats know live.